# Converting std::array to C# array using SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig, stdarray

I'm trying to wrap a C++ class using std::array. In C# I'd like to use this std::array as a normal array. The C++ class could look like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <array>

struct Data
{
    int member1, member2;
};

class TestClass
{
public:
    std::array<Data, 2> GetExampleArray() {
        Data item1;
        Data item2;

        item1.member1 = 0; // Initialize with some boring data
        item1.member2 = 1;
        item2.member1 = 3;
        item2.member2 = 4;
        return { item1, item2 };
    }
};
```

Usage in C# would be as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        Data myData = testClass.GetExampleArray()[0];
        Console.WriteLine(myData.member1);
    }
}
```

My first thought was "Let's pass a pointer to C# using typemaps!" until I realized that this is no C-style array and even if it was I wouldn't be able to pass the length.
So my question is: Which steps can I take to get its data into a C# array?

Comment: [`%include <std_array.i>`](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/csharp/std_array.i)?

Comment: Looks like my SWIG version was a few commits too old. This file didn't exist there... Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved by updating the SWIG version.